# $U \cap \operatorname{cl}(A) \neq \emptyset$ implies $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$, is $U$ open?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In a metric space $(X,d)$, let $U\subseteq X$. If $$U \cap \operatorname{cl}(A)\neq \emptyset \implies U\cap A\neq \emptyset$$ for all set $A\subseteq X$ , is $U$ open? (Notation: $\operatorname{cl}(A)$ is the closure of $A$)

I am currently stuck at this problem for a long time, the converse is easy and there are many similar ones out there.

Any proofs or hints? Or any counter examples if not true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $cl(A)$?

Comment: @math The closure of $A$.

Comment: Sorry, $cl(A)$ is the closure of A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specializing the property to $A=X\setminus U$, we have $$X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus U)\subseteq X\setminus (X\setminus U)=U\stackrel{\text{because }U\cap(X\setminus U)=\emptyset}{\subseteq} X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus U)$$

And therefore $U=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus U)$, which is open.

Comment: It's a very interesting proof, thanks! But there is one thing I want to confirm: $U\subseteq X\setminus\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus U)$ used the contrapositive condition that $U\cap A =\emptyset \implies U\cap \operatorname{cl}(A)=\emptyset$, is it correct?

Comment: @Felicks Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

You could also prove the contrapositive. Suppose that $U$ is not open then we can find a set $A$ such that $cl(A)\cap U \neq \emptyset$ but $A \cap U = \emptyset$. To see this let $x \in U$ be such that $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$ is not a subset for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then we can construct a sequence $(x_n)_n$ by letting $x_n \in B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x) \setminus U \neq \emptyset$. Then let $A=\{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and notice that $A \cap U = \emptyset$ but $x \in cl(A)$ so $cl(A) \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Very nice and clear proof, thanks! I wish I can accept both answers.

Comment: No worries at all just glad I could give a different perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in U$. If $x$ is **not** an interior point of $U$, this means that every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $X\setminus U$. So $x \in A \cap \operatorname{cl}(X\setminus U)$. By the assumption on $U$, applied to $A=X\setminus U$, we would conclude that $U \cap (X\setminus U) \neq \emptyset$, a contradiction. It follows that $x$ *is* an interior point of $U$ and as $x$ was arbitrary, $U$ is open. QED